# Within-group synchronization in OpenCL kernel, which use spinlock on local memory

Tags: synchronization, opencl, nvidia, spinlock

I am trying to run the following code on NVIDIA GPU, but I get different results each time. As far as I could figure out, the problem is not with the spinlock itself (it correctly enforces the locking of the variable in local memory), but with the broken barrier after the `atomicFunc` call. I tried to run this example with 1 workgroup of size 256. The problem is observed only on NVIDIA GPU.

```cpp
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable

int baseFunc(private int x)
{
    return (x + 1);
}

int atomicFunc(__local int* localAccMutex, __local int* x)
{
    int oldValue;
    bool flag = 1;
    while (flag) {
        int old = atom_xchg(&localAccMutex[0], 1);
        if (old == 0) {
            oldValue = *x;
            *x = baseFunc(*x);
            atom_xchg(&localAccMutex[0], 0);
            flag = 0;
        };
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    };
    return oldValue;
}

__kernel void kernel(__global int* result)
{
    __local int localAcc[1];
    __local int localAccMutex[1];

    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) {
        localAccMutex[0] = 0;
    };
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) {
        localAcc[0] = 0;
    };
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    atomicFunc(localAccMutex, &localAcc[0]);
    // warps are ignoring this barrier
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) {
        result[0] = localAcc[0];
    };
}
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be the barrier inside `while(flag)`. According to `barrier` specification:

> This function must be
> encountered by all work-items in a work-group
> executing the kernel.

> If barrier is inside a loop, all work-items must
> execute the barrier for each iteration of the loop
> before any are allowed to continue execution
> beyond the barrier.

You also don't need to run `atom_xchg(&localAccMutex[0], 0)` after you have changed the value to one. You can flip the checked value each iteration instead:

```cpp
int atomicFunc(__local int* localAccMutex, __local int* x)
{
    int oldValue;
    int flip = 0;
    bool flag = 1;
    while (flag) {
        int old = atom_xchg(&localAccMutex[0], 1 - flip);
        if (old == flip) {
            oldValue = *x;
            *x = baseFunc(*x);
            flag = 0;
        }
        flip = 1 - flip; // 0 -> 1; 1 -> 0
    }
    return oldValue;
}
```